# How to abind matrixs of different dimensions?

Tags: r

I have 2 matrixes of dimension `c(1,2,1)` and `c(1,2,2)`. How can I `abind` them to form an array?
If there is no way to `abind` them, how to store this data in one accessible array?

```
a = c(45,75)
b = rbind(c(50,85),c(70,20))

Step 1:
m = NULL
m = abind(a,m, along = 3)

Step 2:
m = abind(m, b, along = 3)
```

The result should be an array with 2 lines, 2 columns, and the third dimension would be as long as the longest between a and b, i.e. 2. Do you know how to do it?

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example

Comment: Welcome to [so]! Please read [ask] and give a [mre] in your question!

Comment: Thank you for your advice, I have changed the question.

Comment: @akrun do you have any idea on how to make it ?